# How to encrypt the following input and store it in mongodb given the schema

Tags: json, mongodb, encryption

I need the value of the 2 variables separate to encrypt and store as different values.

```js
var newSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    type:String,
    name:String
});

module.exports = restful.model('abc',newSchema);
var db=req.db;
var collection = db.get('abc');
collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
    res.send(
    (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module to encrypt/decrypt before you send to the db.

You would want to replace each item in req.body that you want to encrypt. Like:

```
const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', secret);
cipher.update(req.body.type, 'utf8', 'base64');

req.body.type = cryptocipher.final('base64')
```

Example of pbkdf2 key hashing.

```
var plain = 'my password';
var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')


crypto.pbkdf2(plain, salt, 100000, 512, 'sha512', function(err, key){
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(key.toString('hex'));       

});
```

Note: Vary the 10000 (iteration count) as a tradeoff between speed and security.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to maintain json structure in req.body even after it's encrypted because of "Collection.insert(req.body)" wont accept it after I just used crypto or bcrypt on req.body directly. Can you show me how to do that? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I am using CyptoJS for encryption and it's storing encrypted string but when decrypting ,I'm getting 'cannot find Salt of undefined' It's really urgent.

Comment: You have to generate it like `var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')`.